# Regarding MS Win 2008 Server Issue

Tags: crash, windows-server-2008

I have been working for an installer in VC. Although it is working fine with Windows 2000, XP and Windows 2003, its not working under Windows 2008 and Vista after a crash. Interestingly it will work like a charm as and when I changed the executable name.

I'll explain briefly what i did in Windows 2008 and Vista.

My executable's name is Setup.EXE.

1. Starting the installation for the first time.
2. I have to abort the installation whenever the setup dosen't meet any prerequisites like IIS is not installed.
3. Application gets aborted because of lack of prerequisites.
4. I had made available all prerequisites.
5. Trying to install again.
6. Setup.EXE crashed.
7. I had changed Setup.exe to __setup.exe.
8. Trying to install again.
9. Installed successfully.

I could not run the application with name as Setup.exe again.

Can you please tell me what is wrong here?

Regards,

Harish

Answer (score 0):

To further analyze this, the call stack for the crashed application is required.

Answer (score 0):

If vista/2008 starts an executable with the name of setup.exe it will automatically elevate.